# ArcGIS JS API Measurement widget change measurement units text?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The ArcGIS Server JavaScript API has a [Measurement widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/measurement-amd.html), which reports the area or length of a shape drawn on the map.

The default metric labels use the American spelling of "Sq Kilometers" and "Kilometers", etc.

[image]

```
var measurement = new Measurement({
        map: map,
        defaultAreaUnit: units.SQUARE_KILOMETERS,
        defaultLengthUnit: units.KILOMETERS
}, dom.byId("measurementDiv"));


measurement.startup();
```

Is it possible to change the default text "Square Kilometers" shown by default to a custom text (like "km<sup>2</sup>")?

The Measurement widget doesn't seem to have any customisation options which would accomplish this.

Comment: What version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript are you using?

Comment: It will most likely be 3.x or 4.x.  10.2 may be your Server version.

Comment: @PolyGeo yeah, you're right. Api is v 3.13

Comment: @StephenLead i think the same.I have no idea about building my own measuring widget. Could you suggest some reading materials? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this string, like many other strings in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, by taking advantage/overwriting the localizable strings.

This is documented at the bottom of the localization doc - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/localization.html

```
require([..., "dojo/i18n!esri/nls/jsapi", ... ],
  function(..., bundle, ...) {
    bundle.widgets.measurement.NLS_area_sq_kilometers = "km<sup>2</sup>";
    // or bundle.widgets.measurement.NLS_area_sq_kilometers = "km2";
  }
);
```

Comment: Well, i would have preferred to have a nice "setText" method or something in that vein. But your solution does it. Thank you very much.